# Google Apps Script trigger takes over 30 seconds to execute

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Form which is linked to a Google Sheet for when the form is submitted. It should instantly hit a trigger which executes some Google Apps Script.

It use to instantly trigger how it should but now it takes anywhere from 34 to 42 seconds for the code to execute.

I've tried Google Support and they didn't know the answer and they told me to ask on here.

Has anyone come across this? Is my account being throttled? How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: If you provide your code, people are able to review it. See if it can be optimized. Since you've already contacted Google Support I'd say this has nothing to do with throttling as they'd be perfectly able to point this out for you.

Comment: The Google support rep didn't really know what App Script was. I've tested it with just a simple script where all it does is send an email. It has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: This website is meant for programming questions, so if you are 100% sure your issues does not relate to your code, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Google Support sent me here... This is the only Google Apps Script place to ask questions. They said this would be the official forums for Google

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but this is not Google's official forum, even if they try to say it is. If you have an issue with Google's service quality - such as the time it takes between action and listener, then you can only take that up with Google. Use their public issue tracker.